# Is there a way to limit SharePoint Online usage to users (or a group of users) to the offfice premises ( Physical location ) only?

Tags: sharepoint-online

A superior would only want SharePoint Online to be used within the office confines ( the physical work place ) and not accessible outside much like an intranet?

We will in the future hope to move towards a hybrid solution but for now SharePoint Online is our front runner to get things started.
But they don;t want users to access the site from outside the work environment.

Comment: And the same pointy haired boss will raise hell next week when he can't access his files from the airport ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open up the Admin Centre for SharePoint Online.

In the left navigation, click device access.

In the section for `Control access based on network location`, select `Only allow access from specific IP address locations`

Enter the IP address or address range/s for your corporate networks.

This will prevent users outside of these ranges from accessing SharePoint online.

Answer (score 3):

Open **Admin Center** of your SharePoint Online.

In the left navigation, click on **"Access Control"**.

In the section for **Control access based on network location**, select **Only allow access from specific IP address locations**

Enter the IP address or address range/s for your corporate networks.

Please find the below Microsoft article for your reference :

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/control-access-to-sharepoint-online-and-onedrive-data-based-on-network-location-b5a5f1f1-1174-4c6b-91d0-9273a6b6971f

Answer (score 2):

If you have the applicable enterprise licence agreement you can do this using Azure AD Conditional Access in the Azure Portal.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access-azure-portal

This approach might be preferable because you can provide more granular access instead of a block at IP address level.  In future when your pointy haired boss learns the true value of SharePoint Online for external access you may be able to lift the policy gently if you've implemented conditional access.